# Missing MD5Sums control file

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Forgive my Linux newbness....

I've just run this: `dpkg -C`

and it returned the following:

> The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
> database, they need to be reinstalled:  module-init-tools
> transitional dummy package (module-init-tools to kmod)  libjson0:amd64
> JSON manipulation library (transitional package)

How do I go about rectifying this/these issue(s) ???

P.s. At this point I've not tried to do anything to fix them since I'd be throwing blunt knives at under inflated balloons in the dark, and I really don't want to mess anything up.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall them? (see http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get if you don't know how to do that)

Comment: I didn't know how to so safely. It appears to be fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear the fairly simple solution -once you know how- is to reinstall the two packages with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libjson0:amd64
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall module-init-tools
```